# Application is Crashing when trying to request for no tilte bar

Tags: android, android-studio

My Application is crashing when i try to request for no title bar

> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>                this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
>                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
>           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

---

Comment: is your activity extending ActionBarActivity?

Comment: put your logcat here and explain in detail.

Comment: Yes,
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String phonenumber;
    EditText phone;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
         //         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//int flag, int mask
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: try to just extend Activity class to your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.xml write following code :

```
<style name="NoAB" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

And apply this theme in the activity in which you want to hide the actionbar

```
<activity
            android:name=".<YourActivity>"
            android:theme="@style/NoAB" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`